# Balancing parentheses using stack data type in C

Tags: c

I have this stack data structure, in which I store the data in an array. The stack is defined in the struct stack and type defined as Stack. So, I am using this stack data type to check whether in a given string the parentheses are balanced are not.

I am reading in the value using the get line function. But somehow, if I give the total length of read string into my function isBalanced(buffer,strlen(buffer)), I get right answer but with an erroneous output. I get this as the output:
Stack underflow: there are no elements in the stack
The expression is balanced

The first line should not be there because in the isBalanced function, I have placed a lot of checks. Even if it manages to pass this condition matching(peek(s),exp[i]), though it should not, it still has to go through  if (isEmpty(s)) return 0; this test condition, which should ensure that program exits and does not give the Stack underflow message,
Here is my code, please help me find the problem, in earlier implementation. Though I have the right answer now, by passing one less than the total number of characters read by get line function. I guess '\0' is the problem, but I am not sure why is this behavior so weird:

```
// This is the stack data struct definition
typedef struct stack{
    int top; //keeps track of top most element in the stack
    int capacity; //keeps track of number of elements that could be stored
                  // in the stack
    int *array;
} Stack;



// This is the stackInterface.h file
#include "stack.h"

//To create a stack
Stack *createStack(int);

//Queries about the status of stack
int isEmpty(Stack *);
int isFull(Stack *);

//Methods to update stack
void push(Stack *, int);
int pop(Stack *);

//Method to look at the top element of the stack
int peek(Stack *);



// This is the linking file to the main executable file
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "stack.h"

Stack *createStack(int capacity){
    Stack *s = malloc(sizeof *s); //new stack is created
    s->top = -1; // initially top position is empty and hence initialised
                // to -1.
    s->capacity = capacity;
    s->array = malloc(sizeof int*capacity);
    // an array with required capacity is created
    return s;  // pointer to newly created stack is returned

}

int isFull(Stack *s){
    return s->top == s->capacity - 1;
    //A short-hand of way of writing that if the top is equal to the
    //number of elements in the stack return 1.

}

int isEmpty(Stack *s){
    return s->top == -1;
    //top value being -1 signifies that there are no elements in the stack
}

void push(Stack *s, int value){
    if (!isFull(s))
            s->array[++s->top] = value;
       //Incrementing the top position and placing the value at that position
    else
            printf("Stack overflow : the stack is at capacity \n");
}

int pop(Stack *s){
    if (!isEmpty(s))
            return s->array[s->top--];
    //returning the value at top position and decrementing the top position
    printf("Stack underflow: there are no elements in the stack\n");
    return INT_MIN; // some sentinel value is returned to signify failure
}

int peek(Stack *s){
    if (!isEmpty(s))
            return s->array[s->top];  
    printf("Stack underflow : there are no elements in the stack\n");
    return INT_MIN;   // some sentinel value is returned to signify failure
}


// This is the main file
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stackInterface.h"

int matching(char ch1, char ch2){
  return (ch1=='{'&&ch2=='}')||(ch1=='['&&ch2==']')||(ch1=='('&&ch2==')');
    // both ch1 and ch2 should be of matching types

}

int isBalanced(char exp[], int size){
    int i = 0;
    Stack *s = createStack(size);
    while (i < size){
            if (exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '[' || exp[i] == '('){
                    push(s, exp[i]);
            }
            else{
                    if (matching(peek(s),exp[i])){
                            if (isEmpty(s)) return 0;
                            pop(s);
                    }
            }
            i++;
    }
    return isEmpty(s);
}

int main(){
    size_t buf_size = 32;
    ssize_t characters;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    characters = getline(&buffer, &buf_size, stdin);
    puts(buffer);


    if (isBalanced(buffer,strlen(buffer)-1))
            printf("The expression is balanced \n");
    else
            printf("The expression is not balanced \n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output which I get if I remove the -1 form isBalanced function should not      be there at all:
    "Stack underflow: there are no elements in the stack" as the first line. And "The expression is balanced" as the second line. The second line is fine, but looking at the code, one can see that the first line should have not been there, due to a lot of checks there.

Comment: One problem-- you are not initializing `buffer` and `buf_size` before calling getline. They may be set to 0, but then again they may not, so you can't be sure what will happen.

Comment: You need to initialize `buffer` to NULL before calling getline.

Comment: I checked by adding your suggestion to my code, it didn't have any change. The output was still the same. Please see that if I reduce the length of string in the isBalanced function by 1 i.e. by excluding the '\0' at the end of string, I get desired output. But without it, I don't and I have no idea why its not working this way. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

`getline()` includes the newline character (\n) in the buffer, which does not match anything. The stack is empty by that point and so you get an underflow error, but because the stack is empty, `isBalanced()` still returns true. By passing `strlen(buffer) - 1` you are leaving off the newline character and that's why things seem to work.

Also, you need to initialize `buffer` and `buf_size` to zero before calling `getline()`.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. But my problem is in comprehending how come matching(peek(s),exp[i]) is evaluating to true and why not my test condition of if (isEmpty(s)) not returning true value, because the stack is empty by this point, but it still gives false, and somehow even without a match matching function evaluates to true. There's no such condition in the matching function, but it still evaluates to true.

Comment: `matching()` evaluates to false for the newline character, but that does not cause `isBalanced()` to return false. There is no else clause for the if statement, so the body of the if is not executed. Instead `i` is incremented and then the loop ends. Because the stack is empty, `isBalanced()` returns true.

Comment: "how come matching(peek(s),exp[i]) is evaluating to true". It is not. Perhaps the fact that you algorithm fails on `(])` will shed some light on this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I got the problem.

Comment: There is also a "Stack underflow: there are no elements in the stack" message in the `peek()` function in your code. It is the `peek()` function which is printing the message about the underflow, not `pop()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mark, I got the problem. Sorry for wasting your time by overlooking the print statement inside the function